# Is Arya the real Arya, or is Arya being impersonated by The Waif?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Since being in the House of Black and White, Arya seems to be a little different. Sure, she traveled across the whole country and went to hell and back, but somehow after her battle in Braavos Arya had changed a lot of her behaviour:

- She switched her hair from traditional Arya to "The Waif"-hairstyle.
- She used to be right-handed, now she is fighting with her left hand (compare the Arya-Brienne fight in season 7, episode 3)
- she has few to no characteristics left in her
- she switched her communication style (from lying a lot to being honest)

One could assume that The Waif was victorious over Arya and is now impersonating Arya for a greater purpose.

Or did I miss the scene where The Waif finally gets killed? As far as I know the exact fighting scene is just the escape, followed by a "blackout fight" in the dorms where Arya sleeps.

Comment: “compare the Arya-Brienne-Fight in season 7, episode 3” — compare it to what? When did she fight with her right hand?

Comment: She never was right handed...

Comment: Already has the answer here : https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78549/is-the-waif-wearing-aryas-face

Comment: @Bebs she stabs the hound right-handed

Comment: What would be the Waif's motive for going after the Freys?  For threatening to kill Cersei?  For going to Winterfell at all?

Comment: @Edlothiad: when did Arya stab the Hound?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite while she was travelling with him and practicing her water dancing. It's part of why she knows to attack Brianne at the weak points in her armour. She stabs the hound and he blade does nothing to his armour. He then slaps her to the ground

Comment: Hi again max. Please accept the answer (click the little green tick) which you think most accurately answers your question.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

### Arya kills the waif in Episode 8 of Season 6.

Jaqen walking through the House of Black and White and finds a trail of blood. After following the trail he finds the Waifs face on the wall of faces.

The scene can be scene in the video below.

As for the rest of your points, I'll cover them one by one

### 1. Arya's new hairstyle is reflective of that of Ned in Season 1, similar to her dress style, it mimics Ned's outfit the last time she saw him

[image: Ned looking like arya[1]]

### 2. She was always left-handed. In this gif with Syrio Forel, we can see she's fighting with her left hand:

[image: Left-handed arya[2]]

3. As for points 3 and 4, this seems to be some sort of character arc we missed, where Arya becomes this hardened killer that is very honest because she fears no one anymore. This being traits she'd learnt during her time at the Faceless Men and skills she's practiced since then. We see these traits in several scenes this season. This seems to be similar to Bran's sudden Three-eyed Raven skills.

---

[@Mat's Mug](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/54061/mats-mug) suggested that Nymeria's taking to Arya in S07E02 suggests the certainty that it was Arya. Nymeria would likely have munched anyone else's head off. As the Nymeria and her pack are known for attacking Men, as in ASoS Arya wargs into Nymeria attacking the Bloody Mummers.

Comment: In the books (can't remember if the series paid much attention to it) Syrio Forel explicitly mentioned that Arya being left-handed is an advantage, due to people not being used to fighting against left-handed opponents. *Arya took her right hand off the grip and wiped her sweaty palm on her pants. She held the sword in her left hand. He seemed to approve. "The left is good. All is reversed, it will make your enemies more awkward."*

Comment: We can't say definitively that she killed the waif. The waif could have been wearing a mask all along and put that into the house while wearing an Arya mask. There is a lot of other evidence to suggest she didn't though.

Comment: @TimB Nymeria (S7E2) would have made a single bite of the Waif. That Waif theory is outright nuts. *"A girl is Arya Stark of Winterfell. And I'm going home."*

Comment: @TimB I feel like Jaq'en would know what The Waif's original face looked like

Comment: @TimB The Waif's face appears in the Hall of Faces after Arya kills her. Tough to come back after that. http://i.imgur.com/0pv2fZ2.png

Comment: I agree with the conclusion in this, based on the wolf evidence. But another piece of evidence for devil's advocate is that when Jaquen says "Finally a girl is no one" it could be seen as he is speaking to the waif wearing Arya's face after the waif having *removed her own face* to hang on the wall, that latter act being the one that makes her no one.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64052/discussion-on-answer-by-edlothiad-is-arya-the-real-arya-or-is-arya-being-impers).

Comment: @Paulie_D `The Waif's face appears in the Hall of Faces after Arya kills her` Assuming that the face we've seen the Waif with is her original face, then yes. Let's say <Unknown faceless man> kills the Waif. <Unknown faceless man> starts wearing the waif. <Unknown faceless man> kills Arya. <Unknown faceless man> puts the waif's face in the Hall of Faces, and leaves wearing Arya's face. That's the point @TimB was making.

Comment: Let's not forget, the faceless men are *magic*. They aren't simply wearing a mask made out of skin. They **become** the mask. Their voice, height, and build changes. They feel what the other person felt. Unless "seeing through magical illusions" is one of the Dire Wolves natural gifts, there is no way Nymeria would have been able to tell the difference between Arya and the Waif wearing Arya. That's the whole point of the Faceless men. I'm certain that Arya killed the Waif. But there is no way we can ever actually *know*.

Comment: @Shane: Even if fake-Arya is completely convincing to Nymeria (which somewhat goes against the general trope of animal instinct, but let's forget that for a second), that doesn't prove how fake-Arya knows about Nymeria, and is able to recognize her. Arya convinces Nymeria that it's her, Nymeria didn't really make the first move there. That requires Arya to _know_ that it is Nymeria. Even if the waif knew about Nymeria's existence, she has never seen her. There is no proof for this theory that hasn't already been refuted in this answer. Nothing seem (wrongly) out of place with Arya.

Comment: @Flater No, no. In the scene (books) where Arya puts on her first face, it is described how the faceless men gain the memories and personality of the faces they wear as well. They don't get into whether you get *all* the memories or only important ones, but either way, if anyone was wearing Arya, they'd know who Nymeria was. And I agree that there is nothing out of place with Arya. But there wouldn't be even if the Waif was wearing Arya. *That's the whole point of the faceless men* :D. And again, I do believe Arya killed that Waif. The theory is just a fun little "Russell's Teapot" of GoT.

Comment: @Jarko Dubbeldam: In the tv show, Syrio Forel does say it too.The first season was very close to the books.

Answer (score 28):

In addition to the evidence mentioned above there are three more fairly strong bits of evidence:

Firstly there is her encounter with her dire wolf in the forest - it's unlikely the wolf would be fooled by a mask. It's also equally unlikely that the Waif would recognize the wolf. Not only does Arya recognize the wolf and call her by name but she then says "That's not you" in a clear reference to a conversation she'd had with her father many years previously and which again the Waif would not know.

Secondly this dialogue:

> Jaqen H'ghar: Finally a girl is no one.
>
> Arya Stark: A girl is Arya Stark of Winterfell and I'm going home.

The Waif has no reason to lie to Jaqen and also no reason to go to Winterfell or to refer to it as "home".

And finally the elimination of the perpetrators of the red wedding. That was very much something Arya Stark would do (especially the way she did it) but not something The Waif would do.

---

It seems much more likely that the changes you see are the result of the intensive training and experience that she has been through. The lessons from Jaqen were psychological as much as they were physical and they have changed her.

Answer (score 0):

OR is Littlefinger the real Littlefinger or is Littlefinger being impersonated by Arya?

Since he watched Arya sneak into the room and find the letter, we haven't seen them together. Mayber Arya has killed LF and is now impersonating him to control Sansa... Probably not.

Comment: Still an interesting thought on this topic.